# Windows server 2008- domain conflict

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, domain

I was running a windows server 2008 R2 with active directory setup for all the other workstations, which was all setup by someone else before me.
The issue is that the server OS got corrupted a few days ago and I had to reinstall windows in it. Eventhough the server was gone, all the logins in the workstations were working fine (there was centrifydc too installed in the win server, for linux machine logins).
The current situation is, now that the windows is reinstalled and I've installed Active directory in it with the same domain name as before(say company.loc), the logins are not working in the workstations. Yeah, when the server is turned on, all the other workstations are showing invalid login screens. If I turn off the server, they can login fine.
Is there anyway I can keep the current users in the other workstations with the new active directory in the windows server?

Comment: You're going to need to hire a professional who understands the basics of active directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like the workstations are logging in with cached credentials when the new server is offline.  When you recreated the domain it will have generated new UUID's and as you've installed from fresh, you will have had to recreate all of the user and computer accounts generating new UUID's there also.  Without a good backup you are looking at a lot of work to rejoin the clients, fix the user accounts and their workstation profiles and re-permissioning the user data. Do you have any server backups you can restore? or backups of AD?  Do you only have the one domain controller?

Comment: Thanks PaddyT. Then I'm afraid the worst has happened :( No server or AD backups are available here and I've only this one domain controller. I believe, if I'm to recreate the user accounts, the current ones will become unusable?

Comment: afraid not.  You can recreate the accounts/objects with the same names but as they are new you;ll have to go through the process of re-adding the workstations to the domain and then adding the new user accounts into their local groups on the workstations, copy the existing local profiles to the new ones, re-permission any shared CIFS storage and so on.  You are pretty much starting from scratch.